# Trigger only modify updated/inserted row

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi I have the following trigger.

`ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DivisionLastModified] ON [dbo].[tb_Division]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE tb_Division SET  LastModified = GetDate()
END`

This updates all rows however I only wish to modify the update/added row.
Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Because you update all Rows

```
UPDATE tb_Division SET LastModified = GetDate()
```

You must specify the last inserted or updated row id,

so you can specify that in Where condition some thing like this

```
UPDATE tb_Division SET LastModified = GetDate() where id=4
```

Comment: thanks, so now I need to find the identity of the affected row.

Answer (score 0):

To just update LastModified on the rows that were affected by the insert or update you need to use the `inserted` table which is only available in triggers.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DivisionLastModified]
ON [dbo].[tb_Division]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tb_Division
    SET LastModified = GetDate()
    WHERE tb_Division.<Primary Key Column Name Here> IN (
        SELECT <Primary Key Column Name Here> FROM inserted
    )
END
```